# Angular Toggle Button Component remember it's last status

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a component in angular which has a button and an icon.

I need each component instance to remember it's status.

For example:

**app.component.html - 3 instances**

```
<app-view-btn></app-view-btn>
<app-view-btn></app-view-btn>
<app-view-btn></app-view-btn>
```

Then here's is the component code:

**view-btn-component.html**

```
<button>
    <i
        class="fa"
        [ngClass]="status ? 'fa-eye-slash' : 'fa-eye'"
        aria-hidden="true"
        (click)="clickEvent()">
    </i>
</button>
```

**view-btn-component.ts**

```
status: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
  }
```

Right now when I reload the page the components don't remember their last status.

How can I change it so that each component remembers it's status for example using localstorage or other?

Comment: You would have to use localstorage but even further you would have to store them in local storage by name so you can remember which instance had which value.

Comment: Or store them all in an object in localstorage so I can clear them all with one call if needed?

Comment: Yeah you can store them in an object for sure so you dont clutter your local storage. I would pass the name as an input to the view-btn component, get the localstorage object onInit and read the value I needed. You have to make sure you handle the null cases as in when the name doesnt exists and when the object doesnt exist in local storage

Comment: The issue is that I want each component to have it's own unique id, not given by the user. Has each instance of a component have it's own id?

Comment: I left an answer below, refer to that and let me know what you think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: THIS CODE CAN BE GREATLY IMPROVED BUT THE IDEA REMAINS THE SAME!

Create an input for each component to identify it:

```
<app-view-btn [name]="button0"></app-view-btn>
<app-view-btn [name]="button1"></app-view-btn>
<app-view-btn [name]="button2"></app-view-btn>
```

In your ts file you could do something like this. Obviously you would want to make the code a bit cleaner like the JSON parse trick but this is the idea.

```
@Input() name: string;
status: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
// TODO: make this cleaner
const storageValue = localStorage.getItem(this.name)
    this.status = storageValue ? JSON.parse(storageValue) : false;
    }

  clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;
// you could store this in an object
    localStorage.setItem(this.name, JSON.stringify(this.status));
      }
```

Comment: In 'this.status' I get this error: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Try changing 'false' to be just the value false

Comment: Also if this answered fit your use case can you mark it as such so other people can get help if needed

Comment: That's giving me another error: Argument of type 'string | false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: I mean this is trivial in terms of debugging the simple errors its giving you but I updated my answer for your copy-paste pleasure. Stringify the boolean before inserting then in the oninit check if the storage value exists if it doest stringify it else default to false